# Module structure of the homology of spaces endowed with a group action

Tags: algebraic-topology

If $X$ is a topological space endowed with the action of a group $G$, is it true that 
$$ H_n(X,\mathbb{C})  \cong H_n(X) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[G]} \mathbb{C}[G]$$ 
as $\mathbb{C}[G]$-modules?

Edit: Let's say that $X$ is a manifold!